# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException when updating an entity

Tags: java, jpa

I am new to JPA and I am experiencing the following problem, probably due to a not sufficient understanding of cascade and associations? 
I have two entities which are in a bidirectional OneToMany - ManyToOne association:

```
@Entity
public class TestRun implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public TestRun(){

    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(optional=false, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Test performedTest;

    public Test getPerformedTest() {
        return performedTest;
    }

    public void setPerformedTest(Test performedTest) {
        this.performedTest = performedTest;
    }
    .....

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof TestRun)) {
            return false;
        }
        TestRun other = (TestRun) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestRun[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
}
```

And:

```
  @Entity
    public class Test implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;

        @Basic(optional=false) 
        @Column(nullable=false)
         private String name;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="performedTest", cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
        private Collection<TestRun> appearsOnTestRuns;

        public Collection<TestRun> getAppearsOnTestRuns() {
            return appearsOnTestRuns;
        }

        public void setAppearsOnTestRuns(Collection<TestRun> appearsOnTestRuns) {
            this.appearsOnTestRuns = appearsOnTestRuns;
        }
        //id based equals and hashcode
    ...
    }
```

The relationship means that I have a set of Test-s which are perfomed several times, each time being associated with a TestRun. 
To create a TestRun, I use the following method:

```
public void createTestRun(String name){
    Test testPerformed = ejb.findByName(name); //Returns null iff forTest is not in the DB--> INSERT new Test
    if (testPerformed == null){
        testPerformed = EntityFactory.newTest(name);//I set the name for test
    }
    TestRun run = EntityFactory.newTestRun(testPerformed);
    ejb.persist(run);
}

public class EntityFactory{
    public static TestRun newTestRun(Test test){
        TestRun run = new TestRun();
        run.setPerformedTest(test);
        return run;
    }
    public static Test newTest(String name){
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setName(name);
        return test;
    }
}
```

when createTestRun deals with a new Test (insert), the Test object is correctly persisted as well as the TestRun. But when the test already exists, JPA (EclipseLink in my case) tries anyway to execute an INSERT:

```
....
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL110705102925930' defined on 'TEST'.
Error Code: -1
Call: INSERT INTO TEST (ID, NAME) VALUES (?, ?)
```

What does it happen behind the scenes? Does the problem have to do with the appearsOnTestRuns property of Test? Why doesn't JPA understand that Test already exists in the DB (after all, the id property is set during the find operation and equals() uses this value to decide whether 2 Tests are equal..)
Thanks a lot for your help! :)

PS: Do you know a good tutorial / book where these concepts are extensively explained?

Comment: Could you show us the code of EntityFactory.newTestRun(testPerformed)?

Comment: Hi! I have just done it! :) I thought: the Test-s retrieved from the DB get detatched after ejb.find() returns, so the should be manually merged from within the same transaction which will then persist the new TestRun object?

Comment: They should not be detached. The whole createTestRun method should be executed in a single transaction. A transaction should be used for an atomic functional change, not for atomic queries or updates to the database.

Comment: The problem is, I have to build my TestRun object in different times.. Imagine that createTestRun(String name) returns the TestRun object which it created and that, at a second time, another method calls the ejb.persist(testRun).. Do I have to explicitly do:
//Method within an EJB
public void persist(TestRun testRun){
testRun.setPerformedTest(em.merge(testRun.getPerformedTest()));
em.persist(testRun);
}
or is there a better/easier way? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. Another thread will have another TestRun instance. What's the problem? And you still haven't shown the code of EntityFactory.newTestRun(testPerformed).

Comment: What I mean is: first I create a test Run, but I want to store it only when all its associations are set.. the code for EntityFactory.newTestRun(testPerformed) is there after createTestRun().

Comment: Nope. EntityFactory.newTestRun(testPerformed) is called inside createTestRun(). Re-read your code. The outermost method, createestRun, which calls all the other methods, should run inside a single transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should check that the whole `createTestRun` method (which finds the test, creates it if necessary, and then creates the `TestRun` instance and persists it) runs inside a single transaction.

And your newTestRun method should initialize both sides of the relationship, which is bidirectional. It's the responsibility of the developer to maintain the coherence of the entity graph. It should thus do:

```
public static TestRun newTestRun(Test test){
    TestRun run = new TestRun();
    run.setPerformedTest(test);
    test.getAppearsOnTestRuns().add(run);
    return run;
}
```